# Glassfish JDBC + LDAP Realms

Tags: authentication, jdbc, glassfish, ldap

I'd like to authenticate users using both JDBC and LDAP connections. In the database I have usernames, roles, and a flag indicating if the user is allowed to log in.

```
NAME  | ROLE | ALLOWED
user1 | r1   | 1
user2 | r1   | 0
user3 | r4   | 1
```

The LDAP server has the passwords.

I'd like to have the following authentication: If the user is in the database and the `allowed` flag is `1`, then ask the LDAP server for authentication. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure with basic realms within default Glassfish setup but this definitely can be implemented with custom Realm and LoginModule.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7695/beabs/index.html for details.

Comment: And in the custom realm I have to include the JDBC driver manually?

Comment: JDBC driver must be added as a jar to server or domain lib/ directory.